Linkedin signin oauth2.0 not working in springboot application
I have a springboot project which has JWT token authentication. I have added Google sign-In option using oauth2. but now when I'm trying to add linkedin SignIn it is not working. Please help with the below code.
During Google sign debugger is going inside my CustomOauth2UserService loadUser method which is expected but in case of linkedin singin debugger is going inside MyAuthenticationManager authenticate method.

public class MyAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {
    private final UsersRepository usersRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public MyAuthenticationManager(UsersRepository usersRepository,
                                     PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.usersRepository = usersRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        var email = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
        var password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

        var user = usersRepository.findByEmailIgnoreCase(email)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Unknown email: %s".formatted(email)));

        if (!passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid password");
        }
        return user;
    }

}


@Component
public class OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UsersRepository usersRepository;

    public OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler(JwtService jwtService, UsersRepository usersRepository) {
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
        this.usersRepository = usersRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof OAuth2User oauth2User) {
            User user = usersRepository.findByEmailIgnoreCase(oauth2User.getAttribute("email")).orElseThrow();

            if (user.isMfaEnabled()) {
                getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/verify-otp?username=" + user.getUsername());
                return;
            }

            String jwtToken = jwtService.createJwtToken(user);
            response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + jwtToken);
            response.getWriter().write("{\"token\":\"" + jwtToken + "\"}");
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Authentication principal is not an instance of OAuth2User");
        }
    }
}


public class CustomOauth2UserService extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CustomOauth2UserService(UserService userService, UsersRepository usersRepository) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.usersRepository = usersRepository;
    }


    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        log.info("CustomOauth2UserService is invoked");
        OAuth2User oAuth2User = super.loadUser(userRequest);
        RegistrationForm registrationForm = mapOauthUserToRegistrationForm(oAuth2User);
        String email = oAuth2User.getAttribute("email");
        var existingUser = usersRepository.findByEmailIgnoreCase(email);
        User user;
        user = existingUser.orElseGet(() -> userService.createUser(registrationForm));
        return oAuth2User;
    }
    private RegistrationForm mapOauthUserToRegistrationForm(OAuth2User oAuth2User) {
        RegistrationForm registrationForm = new RegistrationForm();
        registrationForm.setEmail(oAuth2User.getAttribute("email"));
        registrationForm.setPassword(String.valueOf(Hex.encodeHex(RandomUtils.nextBytes(32))));
        registrationForm.setFirstName(oAuth2User.getAttribute("given_name"));
        registrationForm.setLastName(oAuth2User.getAttribute("family_name"));
        return registrationForm;
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;
    private final OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    public SecurityConfiguration(JwtFilter jwtFilter, OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler) {
        this.jwtFilter = jwtFilter;
        this.authenticationSuccessHandler = authenticationSuccessHandler;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Password: {}", new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("mellon"));
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            UsersRepository usersRepository,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder
    ) {
        return new MyAuthenticationManager(usersRepository, passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(
            HttpSecurity http,
            CustomOauth2UserService customOauth2UserService,
            CustomOidcUserService customOidcUserService
    ) throws Exception {
        http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/login").authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers(
                            "/signup",
                            "/password-reset/forgot-password"
                    ).permitAll();
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                }).formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login"))
                .oauth2Login(oauth -> oauth
                        .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                        .userInfoEndpoint()
                        .userService(customOauth2UserService))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

   
    @Bean
    public CustomOauth2UserService customOauth2UserService(UserService userService, UsersRepository usersRepository) {
        return new CustomOauth2UserService(userService,usersRepository);
    }
}


Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/14576
Article: https://medium.com/@lucas.rj.fernandes/spring-security-with-oauth2-and-linkedin-a20874ae7477
